# associate 2 lists based on ID

Tags: python

I'm trying to merge data from 2 lists by an ID:

```
list_a = [
(u'65d92438497c', u'compute-0'), 
(u'051df48db621', u'compute-4'), 
(u'd6160db0cbcd', u'compute-3'), 
(u'23fc20b59bd6', u'compute-1'), 
(u'0db2e733520d', u'controller-1'), 
(u'89334dac8a59', u'compute-2'), 
(u'51cf9d50b02e', u'compute-5'), 
(u'f4fe106eaeab', u'controller-2'), 
(u'06cc124662dc', u'controller-0')
]

list_b = [
(u'65d92438497c', u'p06619'), 
(u'051df48db621', u'p06618'), 
(u'd6160db0cbcd', u'p06620'), 
(u'23fc20b59bd6', u'p06622'), 
(u'0db2e733520d', u'p06612'), 
(u'89334dac8a59', u'p06621'), 
(u'51cf9d50b02e', u'p06623'), 
(u'f4fe106eaeab', u'p06611'), 
(u'06cc124662dc', u'p06613')
]

list_ab = [
(u'65d92438497c', u'p06619', u'compute-0'), 
(u'051df48db621', u'p06618', u'compute-4'), 
(u'd6160db0cbcd', u'p06620', u'compute-3'), 
(u'23fc20b59bd6', u'p06622', u'compute-1'), 
(u'0db2e733520d', u'p06612', u'controller-1'), 
(u'89334dac8a59', u'p06621', u'compute-2'), 
(u'51cf9d50b02e', u'p06623', u'compute-5'), 
(u'f4fe106eaeab', u'p06611', u'controller-2'), 
(u'06cc124662dc', u'p06613', u'controller-0')
]
```

You can see that the first field in an ID, identical between list_a and list_b and I need to merge on this value

I'm not sure what type of data I need for `result_ab`
The purpose of this is to find 'compute-0' from 'p06619' so maybe there is a better way than merge.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a one-dimensional list containing a tuple, it could be not needed. Anyway, to obtain the output you require:

```
list_a = [(u'65d92438497c', u'compute-0')]

list_b = [(u'65d92438497c', u'p-06619')]

result_ab = None

if list_a[0][0] == list_b[0][0]:
    result_ab = [tuple(list(list_a[0]) + list(list_b[0][1:]))]
```

Comment: Thank, I think it should work, but my lists will be more than one line | 
with the [0][0], i'm stuck on first lines |
both lists will have the same items, always |
Do you think doing a loop on the number of items in input lists is the best way ?

Comment: by multiple rows you mean that each list can contain more than a tuple? if this is the problem, you can use itertools.combination to compare all the combinations of tuples from the two list

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

```
merge = []
for i in range(0,len(list_a)):
    if list_a[i][0] == list_b[i][0]:
        merge.append([tuple(list(list_a[i]) + list(list_b[i][1:]))])
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to create a dictionary with the keys as the first element of both the lists and values as the list object with all the elements matching that key.

Next, just iterate over the dictionary and create the required new list object:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for elt in list_a:
    res[elt[0]].extend([el for el in elt[1:]])
   
for elt in list_b:
    res[elt[0]].extend([el for el in elt[1:]])

list_ab = []
for key, value in res.items():
    elt = tuple([key, *[val for val in value]])
    list_ab.append(elt)
print(list_ab)
```